# Unable to set the cookie in curl

Tags: php, curl, session-cookies

I used this code to register the site.. But it shows "Your Session Expired, Please Login Again"

It seems that I have some cookie Problem... but I don't understand what is the problem..

and its not the full code. I just posted the main part of it...

```
<?php
session_start();
$r=rand(1,999999999);
$cookie=$r;
$finalcookie="cookie/".$r.".txt";
$_SESSION['cookie']=$r;

$url="http://www.ypox.com";
$login="$url/content/login.html";
$signup="$url/content/signup.action";

$agent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:20.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/20.0";          


$name="Arijit";
$email="dibbyo456@gmail.com";
$mobile="8798147385";
$cap="captcha";

$data="hidGen=Mr&tfUserName=$name&tfMobileNum=$mobile&tfUserID=$email&date1=10%2F10%2F1980&tfReferCode=&textcode=$cap&checkaccept=on";               

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $signup);          
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);          
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR,$finalcookie);          
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE,$finalcookie);          
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);          
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);          
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);     
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $login); 

$html=curl_exec($ch);
echo $html;
```

Answer (score 0):

Every cookie has an unique session id.server keeps track of cookie using that id.In your code you just send a curl request with your cookie but the cookie sessionid is not in record on server as you are generating a cookie code manually.

Comment: what you actually wanna do with these code on ypox ? register or login ?

Comment: Cookie JSESSIONID=EE~498CE23596D22E08BA3DCE8892BE0A01.YP05;http://www.ypox.com/dashBoard.action?id=498CE23596D22E08BA3DCE8892BE0A01.YP05 you can see that the site is forwarding the cookie session id on its url and checking with its cookie..

Comment: here it goes::                                                             http://www.ypox.com/CaptchaServlet?rd=0.20883007500598882 just post a static number.. you will get same captch :) good luck!!

Comment: i already solved the captcha.. 
that's not the problem.
problem is when i running it and echoing the exec its shows "your session expired"